# Using WPF TabControl's ItemsSource property makes the Parent property of its child null

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I'm binding WPF TabControl's ItemsSource property to an ObservableCollection of TabItem.

XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource={Binding TabItems}/>
```

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems {get; set;}
```

With this model, the Parent property of TabItem is always null. However, If I use Items property of TabControl and add the TabItems, the parent property of TabItem in the TabControl is not null. Not sure why it is so.

Answer (score 1):

The parent property returns `null` because the TabItem is not the child of the TabControl. One reason for this to fail is inapropriate `DataContext`s, so the 
XAML Code `<TabControl ItemsSource={Binding TabItems}/>` could fail.

Check if the DataContexts are proper. 
If you are having trouble in checking the `DataContext`, try Snoop, a handy program every WPF developer must have :) [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

Start Snoop, ask it to 'Snoop' your running program, a window appears with Visual Hierarchy on the left. Drill down to your `TabControl` and check its DataContext on the right (Its the second tab item, RightTop). Verify it shows your property you defined `TabItems` (`public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems {get; set;}`)

Hope it helps :)